# Bing maps traffic API not returning any data?

Tags: bing-maps

I've been attempting to use the Bing traffic API to return traffic data for a specific area, but I never seem to get any traffic info back, even at peak hours when I can see several incidents listed with the [BBC Travel](http://www.bbc.co.uk/travelnews/bristol%20BBC%20Travel) website.

I haven't been able to find a way through the Bing API to show a bounding box on a map to verify that I'm getting the right area, but when I display the bounding rectangle on a google map, it covers the area that I'm interested in.  I've also tried expanding the area considerably to include surrounding areas, and then I do sometimes get some data, but that seems quite erratic and disappears again when I expand the bounding box again??

The URL I'm using is:

http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Traffic/Incidents/51.4,-2.8,51.7,-2.3/true?o=xml&key=MyKey
(South, West, North, East co-ordinates).

And it covers the following area on a google map, which is exactly what I'm expecting:

[image: Map]

Am I doing something completely wrong with the API call or is this some weird behaviour that shouldn't be happening?

Answer (score 1):

The BBC pulls in their Traffic incident data from a different source. Looking into the Traffic Manager Module in the Bing Maps V7 control I do see some incidents, not the same as the BBC though. The Bing Maps control also has traffic flow maps as well.

[image]

Here are a couple of other API's you can try out: 
http://data.gov.uk/dataset/live-traffic-information-from-the-highways-agency-road-network
http://www.highways.gov.uk/traffic-information/

Comment: Thanks - I assumed that the BBC got their data from somewhere else, but thought that if an incident came up on the BBC as severe it would also be in the bing traffic data.  Obviously not!  I did see the highways XML data before but didn't find it very easy to work with, will give it another go though, thanks.